# Binding Two-ways : array of numbers within angular application

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, binding

I need to bind an array of number in two ways with a set of input number:

**Ligne.Component.ts**

```
export class LigneComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() cells: Array<number>;

  constructor(private lgservice: LigneserviceService ) {
    this.lgservice.init(4032,10);
    this.cells = this.lgservice.cells;
    }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onSearchChange() {

      for (let cell of this.cells) {
      {
        console.log(cell);
      }
  }
}
```

**Ligne.Component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let cell of cells">
  <input value="{{cell}}" type="number" [min]="0" [max] ="9" maxlength="1" class="row" (input)="onSearchChange()" >
</div>
```

It seems that the binding works in a single ways ie : I get the default values ( equal 0 ). But when I Change the value of the cells I get always 0 as value of all cells !!

So I need to know how can I fix this problem?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using incorrect binding for value. You should use `ngModel` here.
Also your cell should be an object with some field holding a number inside it. Then change your template slightly:

```
<div *ngFor="let cell of cells">
  <input [(ngModel)]="cell.field" type="number" [min]="0" [max] ="9" maxlength="1" class="row" (input)="onSearchChange()" >
</div>
```

Comment: I get this error **Uncaught Error: Cannot assign to a reference or variable!**

Comment: Then you probably need to make your cell an object with the field inside it. And use this field in `ngModel` as `cell.field`. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `[(ngModel)]` for two-way data binding but not with the template reference variable. Instead, you should refer to the `cells` item with the array index. In order for the binding to work correctly, you also need to track the items by the index with `trackBy`, as shown in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1oew5j):

```
<div *ngFor="let cell of cells; let i=index; trackBy: trackByIndex;">
  <input [(ngModel)]="cells[i]" type="number" [min]="0" [max]="9" maxlength="1" class="row" (input)="onSearchChange()">
</div>
```

with the code:

```
export class LigneComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() cells: Array<number>;

  ...

  trackByIndex(index: number, cell: any): any {
    return index;
  }
}
```